# End the call in Android

Tags: android, phone-call, telephonymanager

I need to end the declared phone number, but not active, when i have 2 calls (1 active, 1 passive)

This method ends the active phone number only..
How to set phone number?

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

try {
    Method m1 = tm.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
    m1.setAccessible(true);
    Object iTelephony = m1.invoke(tm);
    Method m2 = iTelephony.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("silenceRinger");
    Method m3 = iTelephony.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("endCall");
    m2.invoke(iTelephony);
    m3.invoke(iTelephony);
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: what android version is your target? since marshmallow you can do it with public APIs instead of reflecting private classes

Comment: minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 25

Comment: i know that my answar is late for two years but it can help , your code sound work good , it just can't work in all devices , i have the same code , work in samsung  and oppo but not in xiaomi :) hope im helpful